Opentextfile after file exists
Similar to VBScript OpenTextFile Invalid Proedure call or argument
I'm trying to access a file which seemingly exists, but gives me an error 5.
Here is my code:
`Strfilepath="...\query.txt"
Set DBs = currentdb()

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(strfilepath) then
Set file = fso.opentextfile(strfilepath,ForReading, false, -1)
End if
StrSqlquery= file.readall
File.close

The error occurs on the fso opentextfile line`


I tried the code above

You're missing the opening double quote ". Is this a typo?

Oh, in the create object? Yes that's a typo.. I'll correct that now . It recognises that the file exists, so.. Yes

Not sure, but check the last parameter. -1 opens the file as Unicode, 0 as ASCII and -2 as the system default. See the doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method

I removed the last digit, I  changed it to -2 as well, both gave me the same error 5

Have you defined ForReading?  Either replace it with 1 or add a line at the start Const ForReading = 1

To give you a more detailed response.  You will have read from the documentation that there is a constant value ForReading, but you only have access to this constant, if you reference the related library.  Your code, however, is using what is known as late binding.  It creates an object, which only gets resolved at runtime, and in the process you do not have access to any related constants and enumerations, hence you need to set the value for ForReading yourself.
The alternative approach, which for almost all purposes I recommend, is to use early binding.  To do this, first add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (under Tools, References, scroll down and check the relevant box).  Now you can change your code to something like this:
Dim filepath As String
Dim qry As String
Dim file As TextStream
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
 
    filepath = "C:\test\test.txt"
    If fso.FileExists(filepath) Then
        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(filepath, ForReading, False, 0)
        qry = file.ReadAll
        file.Close
    End If  

Notice that because I have referenced the library, I no longer have to provide a definition for ForReading.  Other advantages are that typos are caught at compile time.  If for example you mis-spell ReadAll as ReadAl you get a compile warning, which you do not get, if you use late binding - the error only comes at runtime, and runtime errors are usually much harder to resolve than compile time ones.

You're the man! Thanks.. Maybe you can help me here too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78304009/passthrough-query-via-vba/78304436#78304436

Your other question is closed!  If the linked duplicate doesn't suffice to get you going, you will need to edit your question to show the query that you are trying to use.  It need not be the exact same query, but it should be structurally equivalent.  If we don't know what you are trying to pass, it is impossible to know how to fix it.
